# Is working though VPN preventing the proxy server from monitoring me?

Tags: vpn, proxy, monitoring, privacy, isp

If I'm working behind proxy. I have a VPN connection outside my country if I used this VPN connection to browse the internet is this hiding me from the proxy? Is it preventing the company proxy or my ISP to monitor my opened web site?

For a weird reason my company (software development company) blocks YouTube, I don't know why! I have a VPN, I don't want to use any anonymous browsing website because it will appear at their site that I'm trying to do something and trying to hide it. That why I think VPN is the right solution but I want to confirm if they will still able to see my opened urls they VPN or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, your question is a bit confusing, but I will try to answer it anyway.

First, your company blocks youtube probably because it hogs bandwidth if used widely throughout the company, and wastes time. I used to handle the firewalls for a company with 52,000 users. Most people did not have Internet access because if every person wasted 1 hour a day, that was a huge amount of money (52,000 hours x $20 hour average = $1,040,000 a day).

So to answer your real question: If you VPN to a VPN server, all they see is the VPN itself, not what you do within the VPN tunnel. That is the point of a VPN: To hide the traffic from anyone, who is not part of the VPN. They will not see your browsing, or be able to monitor it.

Comment: I know your point, as I'm a developer sometimes you need to a video tutorial on specific part of your taks, but also sometimes people just spend their time watch clips (outside work scope).
Thank you for your answer

Comment: of course man, I'm just give a time (day or two max) then I will evaluate

Comment: Though they will, of course, be able to see if you're using a lot of bandwidth, even if they don't know what on.

Comment: It's also very easy to block the VPN port outbound on the firewall. Don't be surprised if you either: a) get fired, b) get the VPN blocked, or c) both (and piss off/get other people fired for doing the same thing)